# Over all features is blue

Tags: cucumber, feature-extraction

[image]

my cucumber shows blue for the features file it needs to be green. how do I do that?
its not working because its blue.

Comment: I tried posting a pic but it wont let me

Comment: You will be able to embed images when you gain enough reputation. I edited your question, since in this case it seems relevant.